Parameters behind non-symmetric Lissajous loop?
I'm trying to guess what kind of two signals can create this kind of Lissajous curve:

However I can't figure out what are the parameters that break the symmetry of the curve. The relative phase creates an elliptic shape but it's symmetric around the center.
Any ideas?

To rephrase your question: find two functions of $\theta$, $f,g$ such that the trace $[x,y]=[f(\theta),g(\theta)]$ traces out your curve.
The quick and dirty solution is to read off the functions $f,g$ defining the origin of your plot to be somewhere in the curve, and drawing rays from the origin, and reading of the $x,y$ of their intersections with the plot, as a function of the angle $\theta$.
A more sophisticated approach, that shows what is going on in terms of the symmetry is the following:
Lets simplify and assume that the loop is parallel to the $x$ axis, (we can rotate later).
Start with a circle:
$$
f=-\cos(\theta);g=\sin(\theta),
$$
(the minus is for convinience later on).
To break the symmetry we need to squeeze $g$ when $f$ approaches 1, that is, $\theta\sim\pi$, so we are looking to multiply $g$ by a periodic function that is positive, and monotonically decreasing in the range $[0,\pi]$. A natural choice is $1-a\cos(\theta)$ where $|a|<1$
so an example of such a function would be $[-\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)(1-a\cos(\theta))]$
Drawing this in Desmos
Now that we are motivated, notice that the y coordinate is (after some trigonometry) $\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}\sin(2\theta)$ which suggests that a Fourier series of the type
$$
g(\theta)=\sum a_{n}\sin(n\theta)
$$
will be a good candidate for generalization. I won't go into this, but you are guaranteed hours of fun with Desmos.
What I do want to point out is that you can squeeze the shape by multiplying the $g$ by some factor $s$, that is $[-\cos(\theta),s(\sin(\theta)-\frac{a}{2}\sin(2\theta))]$ and rotate the entire shape by and angle $\omega$ by the transformation: $[\cos(\omega)f+\sin(\omega)g,\cos(\omega)g-\sin(\omega)f]$
putting this all together in Desmos


What a remarkable answer! Thank you so much!!! I have two questions if you don't mind. 1. Do you think that the possible generation of $g(t)$ could dome from a power of $sin(t)$? 2. Do you think there is a way to include the rotation inside $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ instead of using regular rotation transformation?


do you mean an expansion in powers of $sin(\theta)$?   2. what is the difference between the two options?

